# WPF ComboBox doesn't get initial value

Tags: c#, wpf

View has a combobox with `ObservableCollection<Vendor>` as a source and `SelectedItem` binded to `Contact` which is defined in the ViewModel. Despite successful assigning value to `Contact` in the ViewModels's constructor there is nothing displayed when the view is loaded.

View

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Vendors}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Contact.Vendor, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Id" SelectedValuePath="Key"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          IsEditable="True" />
```

ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<Vendor> vendors;
public ObservableCollection<Vendor> Vendors
{
    get
    {
        if(vendors == null)
        {
            vendors = new ObservableCollection<Vendor>(_contactsRepository.GetVendors());
        }
        return vendors;
    }
    set
    {
        if (vendors == value) return;

        vendors = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private Contact contact;
public Contact Contact
{
    get
    {
        if(contact == null)
        {
            contact = new Contact();
        }
        return contact;
    }
    set
    {
        if (contact == value) return;

        contact = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public ModContactViewModel(ContactsRepository contactsRepository, bool isEditing, Contact contact)
{
    _contactsRepository = contactsRepository;
    IsEditing = isEditing;
    Contact = contact;
}
```

Contact model

```
public class Contact : ObservableObject
{
    private Vendor vendor;
    public Vendor Vendor
    {
        get
        {
            return vendor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (vendor == value) return;

            vendor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string contactId;
    public string ContactId
    {
        get
        {
            return contactId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (contactId == value) return;

            contactId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string contactEmail;
    public string ContactEmail
    {
        get
        {
            return contactEmail;
        }
        set
        {
            if (contactEmail == value) return;

            contactEmail = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string comments;
    public string Comments
    {
        get
        {
            return comments;
        }
        set
        {
            if (comments == value) return;

            comments = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Vendor model

```
public class Vendor : ObservableObject
{
    private int key;
    public int Key
    {
        get
        {
            return key;
        }
        set
        {
            if (key == value) return;

            key = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string id;
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (id == value) return;

            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (name == value) return;

            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The SelectedItem value must compare equal to an element of the ItemsSource collection. That means it must either be an element of the source collection or have an appropriate Equals method override.

Comment: If you bind itemssource to a null collection, then you can find the view does not bind. Make vendors an empty collection initially

Comment: I would rather see initial setup of the vendors and contact done before the viewmodel is presented to the view. Get your data. Set the properties. Avoid weird timing issues and simplify your viewmodels.

Comment: If you are concerned about templating out your view quickly then ensure nothing is null initially. Present the viewmodel, then get the data and set properties so change notifications are raised.

Comment: @Andy Doesn't the lazy initialization prevent collection from being null on binding? As far as I understand here it can only happen if repository returns null. In the second comment you mean to pass the collections as viewmodel's constructor arguments?

Comment: @Clemens Is it a good and clean thing to do to implement it in a model class? Or I should step down and bind it to a key? Maybe a better idea would be to hold only vendor's key there, but I am not sure if I can achieve that as I am not the one responsible for the things that are returned from the database.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking, but you may want to take a look at the SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath properties.

Comment: You haven't bound Vendors using isasync and GetVendors may take some time.

Comment: Calling the vendors only when requested will incur performance penalty, get them as you load. Do it in a separate thread so it doesn't lock your UI.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Won't async calls using the mentioned before in comments XAML tag IsAsync set to true be enough? Is threading a must?

Comment: Threading is not a must, but if your collection takes time to retrieve then for good UX you would retrieve it, as you load the screen in another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the specific instance of the `Vendor` class that the `Contact` object holds is not present in the source collection.

You can either set the `Vendor` property of the `Contact` to an instance that is actually present in the collection. Something like this:

```
public ModContactViewModel(ContactsRepository contactsRepository, bool isEditing, Contact contact)
{
    _contactsRepository = contactsRepository;
    IsEditing = isEditing;
    Contact = contact;

    if (contact?.Vendor != null)
    {
        var vendors = this.Vendors;
        contact.Vendor = vendors?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == contact.Vendor.Id);
    }
}
```

Or you could override the `Equals` method of the `Vendor` class to define that two `Vendor` objects are considered equal if they have the same `Id`:

```
public class Vendor : ObservableObject
{
    ...

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj is Vendor vendor && vendor.Id == Id;
}
```